# Single fql query get latest photos for array of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photos

```
SELECT object_id, src_small FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me())ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```

in the example me() can be replaced with any friend_id , order by "created" is also posible

I am looking for a way to declare friend_id's as array and avoid using fql.multiquery (very slow and got timeouts using node.js)

Thanks